# Adding Sentiments with the same date in R

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I can not find a code to add sentiments for the same dates.

To explain my problem further:

I have a data frame with different articles and dates. I did a Sentiment Analysis for the articles, but some of these got published on the same date.
I need the sentiment for the days and not for each article and i would like to know how to do that.
For example:

```
  SentimentLM     Date
1 -0.0024       2016-02-12   
2  0.0122       2016-08-20
3  0.1203       2016-08-20
4 -0.2256       2016-08-20
5 -0.0024       2016-08-24
...

In this case it should add the sentiments 2,3 and 4 because of the same date that the articles got published on
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider adding an example of your code to the post

Comment: What you are probably looking for is some kind of function that accumulates the values for the same date. I am sure `dplyr` or some such package has the required methods. Please go through the documentation for it

Comment: exactly, i will check the package out and thank you for the help:)